# What "were to " means in these sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context, subjunctives

1. a : What time do you usually get off work?
   b : It depends, but If I were to get off work early, I can.
2. If I were to be born again, I'd like to be born in the states.
3. If I were to be a journalist when I grow up, I'd like to write about music.

What does "were to " mean in these sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every verb in the language except one, you express a hypothetical conditional by using the past of the verb, so

> If I come ...

is not purely hypothetical: I may come, or I may not; but

> If I came ...

is hypothetical: I didn't come/am not coming/am not intending to come, but if I did ...

Exactly one verb has a special form for this, and that is *be*: the form used for a hypothetical conditional is *were* for all personal and numbers (rather than *was* for 1s and 3s). This special form is called "subjunctive".

So

> If I am ready ...

is not hypothetical: I might be ready, I just don't know yet.

> If I were ready

is hypothetical: I'm not, but I'm talking about the hypothetical case.

Your examples use the extended form *if I were to [verb]*. I don't see very much difference in meaning between *If I got off work early* and *if I were to get off work early*, or between *If I were a journalist* and *If I were to be a journalist*. Perhaps the latter has an implication that this was planned: "If I made arrangements to get off work early", and "If I made a decision to be a journalist", but there's not much difference. There's even less between *if I were born again* and *If I were to be born again*.

Answer (score 0):

(1) does not make sense; could it really be 'if I want to get off work early, I can'? (2) and (3) use 'were' in the subjunctive form.

> The subjunctive is a specific verb form. It usually expresses
> something that you wish for, or a hypothetical rather than actual
> situation:
>
> If only I were ten years younger.
>
> I only wish that what you say were true.

[When to use the subjunctive](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825045104/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/when-to-use-the-subjunctive)